# ASP.NET Core 2 POST JSON via AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-core

there seems to be many different topics about this, but barely any of them clearly resolves the problem. At least for me.

**JSON:**

```
{"DocumentDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000","DocumentNumber":"test","RestaurantId":"1","DocumentTypeId":"1","PaymentId":"0","SupplierId":"1","MmRestaurantId":"1","ListOfProductsDto":[["testProd","unit","7","unit2","2","3","19"]]}
```

**AJAX:**

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/Controller/Add/",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("yea");
            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
                alert(errormessage.responseText);
            }
        });
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromBody] DocumentViewModelToSend data)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**Model:**

```
public class DocumentViewModelToSend
{
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DocumentDate { get; set; }

    public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }

    public int DocumentTypeId { get; set; }

    public int PaymentId { get; set; }

    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    public int SupplierId { get; set; }

    public int MmRestaurantId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DocumentProductsDto> ListOfProductsDto { get; set; }
```

Data in controller is always null. How to do it properly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried removing elements from the C# model to find out which one breaks it? I suspect the serializer might not like receiving strings when the model expects numbers.

Comment: All right, its ICollection that causes the problem. But how to solve it?

Comment: `[["testProd","unit","7","unit2","2","3","19"]]` <- here you have an array of arrays of strings. Is that what you intended? If so, you would need something like `ICollection<ICollection<string>>` on the server side.

Comment: Kinda...I wanted to have list of Products, and Product is an object. This could look like: [["testProd","unit","7","unit2","2","3","19"], ["testProd","unit","7","unit2","2","3","19"]]

Comment: If product is an object, you should pass an object instead of an array. So your JSON would look like: `"listOfProductsDto": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]`, for example.

Comment: But in your example, product _isn't an object_, it's an **array of strings**.

Comment: Your C# Model do not correspond exactly with your JSON data. RestaurantId is out of order and the nested collection of DocumentProductsDto is not shown to see if it corresponds with your data example, but It looks weird like an array of strings inside another array.

Comment: John, you are the boss. Thank you so much.